# 'absolute' property not working react native while back to screen android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on react native video conferencing module. I showing complete view of remote video full screen and self video in small screen just bottom right, styles is,

```
remoteView: {
  flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
      alignSelf:'center',
    width: width,
    height: height,
  },

selfView: {
    width:width*.2,
    height:height*.2,
    right:  5,
    bottom: 5,
    position: 'absolute',
    },
```

My Code,

```
return (
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

                {
                  mapHash(this.state.remoteList, function(remote, index) 
                    return (<RTCView key={remoteIndex} streamURL={remoteStreamURL} style={styles.remoteView} />);
                  })
                }
                <RTCView streamURL={this.state.selfViewSrc} style={styles.selfView}/>

<TouchableHighlight 
                    style={styles.otherScreen} 
                    onPress={this._openOtherScreen}>     
                    {
                     (Platform.OS === 'android')
                     ?
                     <Image style={styles.iconnav} source= require('./img/imageP.png')}/>
                     :
                     <Image style={styles.iconnav} source= require('image!imageP')}/>
                    }
            </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight
                   style={styles.quit}
                   onPress={ () => this.closeEvent()
                }>
              {
                (Platform.OS === 'android') ?
                  <Image
                  style={styles.iconnav} 
                  source={require('./img/exit.png')}/>
                  :
                  <Image
                  style={styles.iconnav} 
                  source={require('image!exit')}  />
              }
              </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
  );
```

My mainContainer style is,

```
mainContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
      alignSelf : 'stretch',
      right:  0,
      bottom: 0,
      top:0,
      left:0,
      position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor:'#424242',  
  },
```

Now the scenario is when i open other screen and come back video view screen then my remote view showing me properly but my self video view not showing. But icons showing proper position (Note : i run same code in `iOS` device it working properly not in `android`). I run one test case i make small frame of remote video and again run my application that time when i comeback other screen my self video showing on its position. That means in full remote video it also showing but self video view going back to remote video. How to bring to front my self video.